# Can't tab complete in psql

Tags: macos, tab-completion, psql

For some reason, tab-completion isn't working in `psql` on my Mac. I can tab complete table and field names just fine in Ubuntu, but pressing TAB fails to work in Mac OS X.

I can successfully use my Up/Down arrow keys to navigate back and forth in psql command history, so it's weird that TAB isn't working properly.

Configuration:

- [~/.psqlrc](https://github.com/mcandre/dotfiles/blob/master/.psqlrc)
- [~/.bashrc](https://github.com/mcandre/dotfiles/blob/master/.bashrc)
- [~/.bash_profile](https://github.com/mcandre/dotfiles/blob/master/.bash_profile)

I can reproduce this issue even with .psqlrc disabled (`psql -X`).

System:

```
$ specs psql bash brew terminal os
Specs:

specs 0.12
https://github.com/mcandre/specs#readme

psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.5

bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.45(2)-release (i386-apple-darwin13.0.0)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

brew --version
0.9.5

system_profiler -detailLevel full 2>&1 | grep Terminal -A 5 | grep Version | head -n 1
      Version: 2.4

system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType | grep 'System Version'
      System Version: OS X 10.9.4 (13E28)
```

Comment: OS X uses libedit, rather than GNU Readline, and there have been a long series of bugs in libedit that've affected psql. Perhaps another libedit/readline difference is at fault? (I can't test, as I don't have Apple branded hardware and Apple won't let me run an OS X VM without buying their hardware - rather developer-hostile, no?)

Comment: Yes, I have read about this issue. However, other Mac users are able to use tab completion in Homebrew psql somehow. Hopefully one of them can chime in?